# How to change state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, division

I am having a simple state, which defines a price of the coffee for employees, if the radio button is checked.

```
const [coffee, setCoffee] = useState(0);    
const [checkedCoffee, setCheckedCoffee] = useState(true);
```

This is how I am setting up the new state:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (checkedCoffee) {
            setCoffee(employees * 40);
        } else {
            setCoffee(0);
        }
}, [coffee])
```

But I want to have another option, which will reduce the coffee price 50% and this is how I am trying to handle it:

```
 const handleDivision = () => {
        setCoffee(coffee / 2);
    };
```

And then just calling `handleDivision` in `onClick` button.

```
 <button onClick={handleDivision}>division button</button>
```

The result is just refreshing the price divided by 2 - so something is happening,  but it never actually set up the 50% less price.

Where does my code conflicts?

Comment: where is the code related to `handleDivision` ?? where are you calling it from? please share that part of your code too...

Comment: Are you using function or class components?

Comment: Hey @Riddell , I am using arrow function components.

Comment: Don't use `useEffect`. Just have a handler that set the state when a radio button is changed.

Comment: @Eliot , tell me what does **checkedCoffee** do?? why are you using effect everytime coffee is updated ?? what is relation of `checkedCoffee` to `coffee` ??

Comment: Try this approach: [https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-grothendieck-floly?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-grothendieck-floly?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you @zrna, I just deleted `coffee` from an array in `useEffect` and kept only checkedCoffee. I do have a warning now, but it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `checkedCoffee` to `useEffect` dependency list.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (checkedCoffee) {
    setCoffee(employees * 40);
  } else {
    setCoffee(0);
  }
}, [checkedCoffee]);
```

And then:

```js
...

const handleDivision = () => {
  setCoffee(coffee / 2);
};

return <button onClick={handleDivision}>division button</button>;
...
```

Look at the example here → https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-grothendieck-floly?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey @zrna your solution does work, but now I have warning of missing dependency `coffee` in array. Do you know how to solve it or is it ok to just ignore it ?

Comment: @Eliot it's ok to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the documentation for [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) that it states:

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen. Think of effects as an escape hatch from React’s purely functional world into the imperative world.

Based on the statement from the documentation, it looks like your `useEffect` function will execute again after you've clicked your button and refresh the value based on the `useEffect` function e.g.

```
 if (checkedCoffee) {
     setCoffee(employees * 40);
 } else {
     setCoffee(0);
 }
```

In order to fix this you can remove the `useEffect` call in component and execute the above code inplace or as a seperate function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<button 
     onClick={()=>{
          handleDivision()
     }}>
              division button
</button>`
```

Instead of :

```
<button onClick={handleDivision}>division button</button>
```

Check out this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cache-4c9ud?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same. Updated price shows for a second, but then it comes back to price before 50% division.

Comment: @Eliot are you using some kind of state management libraries??

Comment: Sorry but it is exactly doing same thing . Not correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const handleDivision = () => {
    setCoffee(prevCoffePrice => prevCoffePrice / 2);
};
```